# Creating vcards in C# Working example

Tags: c#, azure, vcf-vcard

I am trying to do a seemingly simple task of creating vcards from a string in c#, but in vain.

I have a simple string in the vcard format as follows::

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Bloggs;Joe;;;
FN:Joe Bloggs
EMAIL;INTERNET;HOME:me@joebloggs.com
TEL;HOME;CELL:+44 20 1234 5678
ADR;HOME:;;1 Trafalgar Square;London;;WC2N;United Kingdom
URL;HOME:http://joebloggs.com
X-SKYPE-USERNAME:joe.bloggs
X-TWITTER:https://twitter.com/joebloggs
END:VCARD
```

and I want to encode that as a file I will then save as .vcf file locally. I have looked at  `Thought.vCards`  and the documentation is nonexistent. It is presumed the individual understands how it works I suppose?

I had a look at `EWSoftware.PDI.Data` likewise, the documentation is pretty much assumptive that the user understands how to use the library is their project.

I WANT:

A simple sample method to create a .vcf file from a string like I shared.

Comment: @Marco You may have saved my life man. I am going to test it and will let you know but it seems pretty much like what I want.

Comment: That did it. It saves the file but there is a permission issue.